# How to return link from jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery autocomplete to add a drop-down box with a string to a text field.

I'd like for part of that string to be an HTML link but according to the documentation it does not seem possible. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each anchor element is treated as an option and rendered accordingly by the autocomplete. You can build your own custom element in order to mimic an anchor. In the example there is an attribute `data-link` that contains the link to open.

Code:

```
$(".field_values").autocomplete({
    source: projects,
    create: function () {
        $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return $('<li>')
                .append('<a>' + item.label + '&nbsp<span href="#" class="mylink" data-link="www.google.it">' + item.value + '</span></a>')
                .appendTo(ul);
        };
    }
});

$(document).on("click", ".mylink", function (e) {
    alert($(this).attr('data-link'));
    $( ".field_values" ).autocomplete( "search");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/3tLrL5aj/

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the url in a span as text and style it using css. Once the user clicks the item in autocomplete (you can use select function of jquery autocomplete) you can perform the required action.